# Generate a randomized hitori board that can be solved with python

Tags: python, random, logic, puzzle, clingo

I have successfully created a clingo asp to solve hitori and it works well for examples of hitori boards found online but on trying to generate a hitori puzzle with random values for my clingo solver, it returns unsatisfiable, below is the code I am using for creating the board

```
import clingo
import random
N = clingo.Number

def randNum(R, n):
    n = n.number
    val = random.randint(1, n)
    if random.randint(0, 9) > 5:
        if val != n:
            n += 1
    else:
        if val != 1:
            val -= 1
    return N(val)
```

I then reference the value for the board with

```
board(1..n, 1..n, @RandNum(R,n)).
```

The table is created successfully and populated with random values but the solver returns unsatisfialbe
Is there a specific method required to create a valid solvable table